# Obtaining random double with inclusive max value (Java - ThreadLocalRandom)

Tags: java, random, double

I have a method to obtain a random double between a min and a max value. My problem is that if the values are for example 0D and 10D I've never obtain 10D as a posible result because nextDouble second parameter is exclusive.

```
public static Double randomDouble(Double min, Double max) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(min, max);
}
```

I've obtain a 10D result if I put this line in my method but I don't know if this is a good practice.

```
public static Double randomDouble(Double min, Double max) {

    max = max + 0.000000000000001D;

    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(min, max);
}
```

Is there another solution for this issue?

Comment: Have you calculated what the probability is of this ever being a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to ignore the issue.

Consider just the simple [0,1] case. I don't know what probability you wish to assign to the upper bound, but the largest reasonable probability is the absolute difference between 1.0 and the largest double less than 1.0. That difference is 2<sup>-53</sup>, about 1.11e-16, which is a very small probability.

The probability of not getting a 1.0 in 1e9 trials would be 0.9999998889777038.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do this:

```
if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() < 0.5) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(min, max);
}
return max - ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, max - min);
```

BUT: While this approach will add your maximum to your possible results, the probability of getting the exact max or min value will actually be only half as big as the probability any other number might have.

Which means that it's pretty much the same as:

```
double result = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(min, max);
if (result == min && Thread.LocalRandom.current().nextDouble() < 0.5) {
    result = max;
}
return result;
```

A slightly better approach might be

```
double result = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(min, max);
if (result != min) {
    result = max - ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, max - min);
}
return result;
```

The probabilities are still uneven, but max actually has the same probablity everything else besides min does. The probability for min is slightly bigger (but really only very slightly, not even comparable to how it was before).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the following code:

```
Random r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
return min + ((double)r.nextLong(9007199254740993L) / 
     9007199254740992.0) * (max - min);
```

Note that part of the code generates a `long` less than 9007199254740993 (2<sup>53</sup>+1) and
divides that by 2<sup>53</sup>, resulting in a number 0 or greater, and 1 or less.  There is also a more sophisticated method, as well as certain subtleties to your problem, which I describe in detail [on another page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1190459/Random-Number-Generation-Methods#RNDU01_Random_Numbers_0_or_Greater_and_1_or_Less); however, the method given in this post will very likely suffice for your purposes.